# Pointer is not being passed during a linked list swap

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, selection-sort

This will most likely seem like I am missing something obvious but when I try to pass a Linked List pointer to my Selection sort I get a NULL pointer problem. In my C code I have this as my linked list:

```
typedef struct iorb
{
    int base_pri;
    struct iorb *link;
    char filler[100];
} IORB;
```

Then I pass my new linked list into this function after creating it:

```
void swapNodes(POINTER *head, POINTER CurrentHead, POINTER CurrentMinimum, POINTER TempSwap);

POINTER SortList(POINTER *head, char *SortMethod[])
{
    POINTER TempHead = *head;

    //Only one node, no need to sort.
    if (TempHead->link == NULL)
    {
        return head;
    }

    //Store node with the new minimum value.
    POINTER TempMin = *head;

    //Store curent node for swapping
    POINTER TempSwap = *head;

    //Transverse the list.
    POINTER TempCurrent;
    for (TempCurrent = *head; TempCurrent->link != NULL; TempCurrent = TempCurrent->link)
    {
        //Check if this node has a lower priority than the current minimum and if so, swap them.
        if (TempCurrent->link->base_pri < TempMin->base_pri)
        {
            TempMin = TempCurrent->link;
            TempSwap = TempCurrent;
        }
    }

    //Swap nodes if the head is not the same as the minimum.
    if (TempMin != TempHead)
    {
        swapNodes(&TempHead, TempHead, TempMin, TempSwap);
    }   

    //Recursively sort the rest of the list.

    //FOR SOME REASON THE NODE POINTER IS NOT BEING PASSED HERE (EMPTY)
    TempHead->link = SortList(TempHead->link, *SortMethod);

    return head;

}

void swapNodes(POINTER *head, POINTER CurrentHead, POINTER CurrentMinimum, POINTER TempSwap)
{
    //Set new head as the minimum.
    *head = CurrentMinimum;

    //Link the current temp swap to the head.
    TempSwap->link = CurrentHead;

    //Swap pointers.
    POINTER temp = CurrentMinimum->link;
    CurrentMinimum->link = CurrentHead->link;
    CurrentHead->link = temp;
}
```

I am not sure why it is isn't being passed back into the same function, when I debug the linked list seems okay. I suspect that I am missing something in the swap node function, but I don't quite understand what this is. Can someone please offer some insight as to how this code should go for swapping the nodes around?

If you need additional information please let me know.

Comment: what is `POINTER`? I don't see it defined. Probably some `typedef` of a pointer, but then, don't do that. It's just confusing ...

Comment: Note: that you are trying to sort a list, by using a selection sort, this is highly ineffective and this is clearly not easy to do with a list, in my opinion this is where you should use a merge sort. It very easy with this kind of data representation.

Comment: `SortList(TempHead->link, *SortMethod);` shouldn't this produce a warning ? You must send the new head address.

Comment: Hi,  Stargateur is right, I was passing this the wrong way. I should have actually written that as &TempHead instead of TempHead->link

Comment: Sorry and just one more thing as well - this is an assignment I have so I am actually required to use the Selection Sort specifically. Perhaps because it is difficult to manage :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SortList(TempHead->link, *SortMethod); needs to be listed as SortList(&TempHead, *SortMethod);

To correctly pass the pointer.